# Calculate mean value of date dependent variable for a certain end and start date taking into consideration groups in R

Tags: r, date, conditional-statements, structure, mean

I have two CSV data sets. The first on is monthly data or a certain variable(PM_2.5) given by spacial constrains (latitude and longitude) which can be seen as the place variables. The second data frame contains different start and end dates for the observation. Also, those are given under the same spacial constraint and for each individual v1. You can see the data structure in the pictures. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAeq3.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAyLv.png)

I want to sum all observations of (PM_2.5) for one individual (ID) over the observation period (start date to end date) given the constraint that the geospatial identification (latitude, longitude) is the same.

Thanks a lot for your help.
Best,
Luise

Comment: Is the observation ID is the index number? Does it match between the two tables?

Comment: Please share sample data as copy/pasteable text, not pictures of tables. The nicest way to share sample data is with `dput()` so all the class and structure information is included too. Enter `dput(your_monthly_data[1:5, ])` for the first 5 rows of your monthly data, and similarly for your other data. Pick a few rows of each that demonstrate the problem, and it often helps us understand and get the right solution if you show the desired output for your sample input.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.